# How to upgrade web application from JSF Mojarra 2.0.5 to the latest Mojara 2.1.9

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I want to upgrade my web application to the latest JSF Mojarra (2.1.9 as of today is the latest) from Mojarra  2.0.5;

How do i do it ?...what are the steps involved ?..
At the moment my web app lib folder has got the old mojarra jars 'jsf-api.jar' and 'jsf-impl.jar'.

It would be a great help if any one can instruct each step . I am on a Websphere Application server 7.0.0.17

Comment: I've only replaced those two JSF libs by `javax.faces.jar` and it works fine

Comment: AS long as your server supports 'Java Servlet3.0' you can use the 'javax.faces.jar' for Mojarra JSF. If your server supports only 'Java Servlet2.5' then you need to have two separate jars(jsf-api.jar & jsf-impl.jsr) for the  Mojarra JSF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the two `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` files from Mojarra 2.0.5 by the single `javax-faces.jar` file from Mojarra 2.1.9.

If Websphere 7 is already configured to use classloader mode "parent last", then you basically don't need to change anything else. But if it isn't (which would basically mean that the webapp-supplied Mojarra 2.0.5 was actually never been used and that Websphere's own JSF libraries is been used instead), then you still need to change the classloader mode to "parent last".

Comment: Just replacing the jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar with javax-faces.jar file from Mojarra 2.1.9 won't work.      This is becoz Websphere 7 server supports only 'Servlet 2.5' and hence can handle only till Mojarra 2.0.9;   And Mojarra 2.1.9 requires java servlet3.0 as a pre-requisite to work

Comment: You'll only miss Servlet 3.0 features such as auto-registration of `FacesServlet`, but if you register it manually in `web.xml`, it'll work as good. Otherwise just stick to Mojarra 2.0.9, which is by the way also just one `javax.faces.jar` file.